# Azure Synapse Create Pipeline Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I am calling Azure Synapse Pipeline Create Pipeline REST API with a Databricks Notebook JSON activity.

Error message in the Synapse Pipeline screen: Could not load resource 'PLDB2'. Please ensure no mistakes in the JSON and that referenced resources exist. Status: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase'), Possible reason: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

PostMan: https://mysynapseworkspace.dev.azuresynapse.net/pipelines/PLDB2?api-version=2020-12-01

Links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/pipeline/create-or-update-pipeline?tabs=HTTP

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-notebook?context=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fcontext%2Fcontext&tabs=synapse-analytics

Create Pipeline JSON in Postman Body

```
{
"name": "PLDB2",
"properties": {
    "description": "Databricks Notebook",
    "activities": [
        {
            "activity": {
                "name": "MyActivity",
                "description": "MyActivity description",
                "type": "DatabricksNotebook",
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "LS_Databricks",  
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "typeProperties": {            
                    "notebookPath": "/Users/abc@myemail.com/Test_Job_1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Synape Pipeline item is created with above error message:

```
{
"id": "/subscriptions/mysubscription/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/mysynapseworkspace/pipelines/PLDB2",
"name": "PLDB2",
"type": "Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/pipelines",
"etag": "9400d55f-0000-0100-0000-63b180e40000",
"properties": {
    "description": "Databricks Notebook",
    "activities": [
        {
            "activity": {
                "name": "MyActivity",
                "description": "MyActivity description",
                "type": "DatabricksNotebook",
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "LS_Databricks_Personify",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "notebookPath": "/Users/nlaw@quaerainsights.com/Test_Job_1"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "lastPublishTime": "2023-01-01T12:47:32Z"
}
```

}

In Azure Synapse,  I can manually create and run a pipeline calling the Databricks "Test_Job_1" notebook described in the JSON.

What is the problem?  Thx for help.

Comment: Using Synapse, I can manually create a Pipeline calling Databricks notebooks.  Is there a method to export the entire underlying Pipeline JSON?

Comment: I found the problem.  In the JSON, delete these 2 lines:  "activity": { and its closing bracket "}"

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. In the JSON, delete these 2 lines: "activity": { and its closing bracket "}"

```
{
"name": "Correct JSON",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "MyActivity",
            "description": "MyActivity description",
            "type": "DatabricksNotebook",
            "linkedServiceName": {
                "referenceName": "LS_Databricks",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "notebookPath": "/Users/abc@myemail.com/Test_Job_1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}